# MATLAB: Return array of values between two co-ordinates in a large matrix (diagonally)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, traversal, edge-detection

If I explain why, this might make more sense

I have a logical matrix (103x3488) output of a photo of a measuring staff having been run through edge detect (1=edge, 0=noedge). Aim- to calculate the distance in pixels between the graduations on the staff. Problem, staff sags in the middle.

Idea: User inputs co-ordinates (using ginput or something) of each end of staff and the midpoint of the sag, then if the edges between these points can be extracted into arrays I can easily find the locations of the edges.

Any way of extracting an array from a matrix in this manner?

Also open to other ideas, only been using matlab for a month, so most functions are unknown to me.

edit:
Link to [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83zlP.png)

It shows a small area of the matrix, so in this example 1 and 2 are the points I want to sample between, and I'd want to return the points that occur along the red line.

Cheers

Comment: Can you post the photo? Its not clear from the post what the "graduations" and "lines" are.

Comment: Sorry I've changed my wording a bit, does the picture make it clearer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
dat=imread('83zlP.png');

figure(1)
pcolor(double(dat))
shading flat
axis equal

% get the line ends
gi=floor(ginput(2))
x=gi(:,1);
y=gi(:,2);

xl=min(x):max(x); % line pixel x coords
yl=floor(interp1(x,y,xl)); % line pixel y coords


pdat=nan(length(xl),1);
for i=1:length(xl)
    pdat(i)=dat(yl(i),xl(i));
end

figure(2)
plot(1:length(xl),pdat)

peaks=find(pdat>40); % threshhold for peak detection
bigpeak=peaks(diff(peaks)>10); % threshold for selecting only edge of peak

hold all
plot(xl(bigpeak),pdat(bigpeak),'x')
meanspacex=mean(diff(xl(bigpeak)));
meanspacey=mean(diff(yl(bigpeak)));
meanspace=sqrt(meanspacex^2+meanspacey^2);
```

The matrix `pdat` gives the pixels along the line you have selected. The `meanspace` is edge spacing in pixel units. The thresholds might need fiddling with, depending on the image.

Comment: No Problem!  Give me a +1 if you like it.

Comment: I will when I'm allowed, apparently I need more reputation first.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing the image, I'm not sure where the "sagging" you're referring to is taking place. The image is rotated, but you can fix that using [`imrotate`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/imrotate.html). The degree to which it needs to be rotated should be easy enough; just input the coordinates `A` and `B` and use the inverse tangent to find the angle offset from 0 degrees.

Regarding the points, once it's aligned straight, all you need to do is specify a row in the image matrix (it would be a 1 x 3448 vector) and use [`find`](http://matlab.izmiran.ru/help/techdoc/ref/find.html) to get non-zero vector indexes. As the rotate function may have interpolated the pixels somewhat, you may get more than one index per "line", but they'll be identifiable as being consecutive numbers, and you can just average them to get an approximate value.

Comment: Thanks, this exactly what I'd already tried (which gives me confidence that it wasn't such a silly idea in the first place), but the image I posted is just a tiny section of whole the image (i.e. about half of it is rotated in the opposite direction - the other side of the sag) so I think picking the points to sample between will make it easier on the larger scale.